# Anaconda's `current_repodata.json` file is causing system to freeze in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04

Whenever I load any IDE, that index the anaconda environment, the system gets freeze, and eventually, have to restart forcefully.

I came to know that its `current_repodata.json` located at `/home/jugs/anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.7.10-py37_0/info/test/tests/data/conda_format_repo/linux-64/current_repodata.json` for ubuntu.

I renamed the anaconda3 [`/home/jugs/anaconda3/`] with any random name [`/home/jugs/oldanaconda3/`], and comment the env path. It works completely fine without anaconda in any IDE (eg: Pycharm or vscode) else it shows scanning the files and indexing and freezes the computer.

Also, whenever I try to update conda or create new environment, the system freezed at `current_repodata.json`.

Comment: Perhaps try cleaning the index? `conda clean --index-cache`

Comment: @merv, no matter what i do, system freezes at `current_repodata.json`. 
I uninstalled anaconda, now when I am trying to install, system freezes at `current_repodata.json`. Now, I can't even install anaconda.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `conda info` to your question?

Comment: @merv, my system freezes, I can't take a screenshot or copy the terminal log unless I restart the computer. I'll try to take a picture and copy here soon.